# Is there any way to bind parameter in select section for TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to implement search with `pg_trgm` module in PostgreSQL on project written with TypeScript and TypeOrm.
SQL what works for me looks like this:

```sql
SELECT t, similarity(t, 'word') AS sml
  FROM test_trgm
  WHERE t % 'word'
  ORDER BY sml DESC, t;
```

But when I started integrate it in my builder I realize that that I can't protect select statement from SQL injection since TypeOrm doesn't offer to bind parameter in any of select methods (such as `SelectQueryBuilder::addSelect`, `SelectQueryBuilder::select`).

Example of my vulnerable method:

```
...
applySearch(builder: SelectQueryBuilder<any>, needle: string) {
    if (needle) {
      builder.addSelect(`similarity(title, ${needle})`);
      builder.andWhere('title % :needle', { needle });
    }
  }
...
```

Maybe somebody know better way to realize this search in my technology stack?

Comment: The use of the query builder is to escape the parameters, all parameters should be escaped. You can try it yourself and see the output query. Read : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3696

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision of this issue was to use same binding key in `where` and `select` statements in next way.

```js
applySearch(builder: SelectQueryBuilder<any>, needle: string) {
    if (needle) {
      builder.addSelect(`similarity(title, :needle)`);
      builder.andWhere('title % :needle', { needle });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

I needed a similar solution, however yours wouldn't cut it for me. If you would like to change your parameter in the select anyway you should look at `setParameter`, which is what the second param of `addWhere` is doing internally.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#using-parameters-to-escape-data

so in your case you could have ran with

```
applySearch(builder: SelectQueryBuilder<any>, needle: string) {
    if (needle) {
      builder.addSelect(`similarity(title, :title)`);
      builder.andWhere('title % :needle', { needle });
      builder.setParameter('title', needle);
    }
  }
```